# Problem with connecting MYSQL in JAVA android app

Tags: java, android, mysql, kotlin

I've tried all methods and ways from stack and videos and none of them actually worked so far.

**MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS**

```java
package com.example.androidmysql;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text;
    Button show;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/example","root","test");
                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");
                    String records ="";
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        records += resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2) + "\n";
                    }
                    text.setText(records);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    text.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The main problem is that JDBC can't connect to database

**OUTPUT**

```
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1009)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
        at com.example.androidmysql.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

- I'm using the latest mysql-connector-8.0.22.
- Added permissions to access internet in manifest
- Installed mysql server 8.0.22
- I've also changed config C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini => bind-address=0.0.0.0
- Tested on different JDK's : 15, 1.8

Here is the code which i uploaded on github. Can someone test it on their pc with their example database?
https://github.com/simplybychris/DatabaseClientApp/tree/master

Database user and password are good, cause I've tested it on separate class without main activity and outside Java project and it works... It looks like it won't work in Mobile Classes

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Do not connect a app directly with a mysql database. You need an backend- application for abstraction

Comment: The reason you don't directly connect like this is that you have to put the password to your db in your app, which is a really bad idea-  its then trivially hacked.  Use a web service in between them.

Comment: BTW you are trying to connect the database on you smartphone (localhost) where no mysql DB is installed

Comment: But I would like to create Database Client App where I can provide URL, user and password to login to database, so theres no point to create Web Service API for it. Or is it?

Comment: @Jens I want to craete App where you can put your database login data and view your database. Something like database client

Comment: @Dray No good idea. You always need a web servcie for a good architecture

Comment: @Jens Okay but how I can send db connection data (url,user,password) to webservice? Normally webservice have config which is configured before running api

Comment: @Dray Don't do it. The db connection shold always known by the backend. If not a user can revers engenier your app and get the information about the db connection

Comment: @Jens you don't understand. I want to access any database, not only one. It's like database viewer where you can manage your database from phone.

Comment: @Jens So I can't preconfigure it in webservice api, cause the login data can change

Comment: @Dray I doesn't make sence in my eyes to manage a db from smartphone, do login by backend after it is started

Comment: @Jens it does. Lets say I want to access different databases from my phone to search for some data.

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mysql-mobile-client/id1406175528

Comment: even apple have app like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why people minusing the question if there is no correct answer. Anyway after 2 days of searching I've finally found the solution. There's the problem while connecting with mysql latest 8.0 driver. I suggest to change it to mysql 5.7.